# Subtracting memory addresses in an array, but it's giving me the actual number

Tags: c++, memory-address, subtraction, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to subtract two memory addresses of two elements in an array, called nums, and I have this:

```
cout << Subtracted memory addresses: << (&nums[50]) - (&nums[0]);
```

The result it's giving me is: 50. It's giving me the actual number and not the memory address.

I've also tried assigning pointers to both nums[50] and nums[0], and then subtracting the pointers, and it gives the exact same result: 50.

I need the actual memory addresses though. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: What address are you trying to get?

Comment: What do you mean by `I need the actual memory addresses though.`? Subtracting two memory addresses can't result in a memory address.

Comment: Pop quiz: how can you figure out the "`sizeof`" of a particular data type is? And, if you know the `sizeof` of one instance of of a type, can you think of a way of using multiplication to compute the `sizeof` `N` of them?

Comment: @NicolBolas I need to subtract the memory addresses of nums[50] and nums[0], and then display a memory address for that result

Comment: @user2348258: Yes, but what address is that? What would that subtraction *mean*? If you add 20 to `&nums[0]`, you get the address of the element with index 20. What address should you get if you do the subtraction you want?

Comment: @tkausl I need the memory address of the actual result of the subtraction. Unless, I'm understanding it wrong, shouldn't my subtraction of the memory address give me back another memory address? Or is it suppose to give me back '50'?

Comment: Subtracting two memory addresses gives you a distance. A distance isn't a memory address.

Comment: @tkausl so there's no way for me to get the memory address of the difference between the elements in nums[50] and nums[0]?

Comment: @user2348258 what do you think "memory address of a difference" means?

Comment: @NicolBolas I should get the memory address for the element with index 50, right?

Comment: _What do you mean by memory address_? There __is no__ memory address of the difference.

Comment: You keep saying that you want this thing. We keep telling you that that makes no sense. You will have to explain in more detailed terms what you expect from this operation. If you subtract "New Zealand" from "Africa", what do you get exactly?

Comment: `I should get the memory address for the element with index 50, right?` The address of element 50 is `&nums[50]`.

Comment: @eerorika I thought it meant subtracting the elements in those indexes, and then getting the memory address of that element

Comment: Why would that be so?

Comment: @user2348258: "*I should get the memory address for the element with index 50, right?*" The only way that A-B should be A is if B is zero. Which a valid pointer is not.

Answer (score 3):

> The result it's giving me is: 50. It's giving me the actual number and not the memory address.

That is what subtracting two memory addresses results in: The distance between those addresses (with the unit being the size of an element). It is unclear *what* memory address you could be expecting to get, but subtracting addresses in not a way to get a memory address.

> I should get the memory address for the element with index 50, right?

No. You get memory address for the element with index 50 like this: `&nums[50]` (or `nums + 50`). That is what you use as the left hand operand of your subtraction. Only way to get the same as the result of the subtraction is if the right hand operand is the zero. Subtracting an integer from an address does result in another address (or in the case of zero, the same address).

Answer (score 0):

That's not what subtraction is.

Subtraction is when you have a thing B, and you remove the quantity of the thing A.

If your 51st element `index[50]` is at `0x110`, then `&index[50]` is `0x110`.

If your 1st element `index[0]` is at `0x010`, then `&index[0]` is `0x010`.

We learnt at school that `0x110 - 0x010` is `0x100`. But, even though I'm writing everything here in base-16 (hex), that's not a memory address. That's the numerical difference between the two values. It's the distance between them.

If you just wanted to know the address of the 51st element, well, that's what you started with: it's `&index[50]`. So just write that.